# preg_match digit sequence separated by a character

Tags: preg-match, digit

How to find two digits separated by the character '-' between a `<div class="lot-price-block">` and closed by `<span`.

I've try this

```
preg_match_all('/<div class=\"lot\-price\-block\">(.*?)<span/s',$file_contents,$estimates);
```

But it give me all the block not only the digits separated by '-'

Someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$file_contents = '<div class="lot-price-block">fsfd 32424-554 fgdf <span';
preg_match_all('/<div class=\"lot-price-block\">\D*(\d+-\d+)\D*<span/s',$file_contents,$estimates);
echo $estimates[1][0];
```

**\D** => Matches everything that's not a digit ([^0-9])

**\d** => Matches everything that's a digit ([0-9])

**ps:** you don't need to escape the hyphens